# Generic method receives generic enum

Tags: java, generics, methods, enums

I would like to have my generic method receiving an enum type which contains the class that I would like to have back from the method.

So this is how far I got (for example):

```
public class Zoo {
   public Monkey apu;
   public Lion simba;
   public Bird zazu;

   public <T extends Animal> T getAnimal(String animal, Animaltype animaltype){
      switch(animal){
         case "apu":
            return animaltype.getType().cast(zoo.feedAnimal(animaltype.getType()))
         case "simba":
            return ??????????????
         case "zazu":
            return ??????????????
      }
   }
}

public enum Animaltype {
   MONKEY(Monkey.class),
   LION(Lion.class),
   BIRD(Bird.class);

   Class <?> enumClass;

   Animaltype(Class<?> enumClass) {
      this.enumClass = enumClass;
   }

   public Class<?> getType(){
      return this.enumClass;
   }
}
```

Now it is saying at the return that the needed one is T and the found one is Object.

error message is:
"Incompatible types Required: T found Java.lang.Object

I don't know the right syntax

Comment: Post the code causing the compilation error, and the exact and complete error.

Comment: It's not going to be possible fill in something for the "?????" that is completely type-safe. You'll need an unchecked cast.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because Java doesn't know what is the type of `T`.

One of the possible solution is just to return `Animal`. In this case you won't need any casting.

```
public Animal getAnimal(String animal, Animaltype animaltype)
```

Also, you can specify the type of `T` by passing `Class<T>` to method instead of `Animaltype animaltype`.

```
public <T extends Animal> T getAnimal(String animal, Class<T> animaltypeClass){
      switch(animal){
         case "apu":
            return animaltypeClass.cast(zoo.feedAnimal(animaltypeClass))
         ...
      }
   }
```

But also field `enumClass` in your enum should be `Class <? extends Animal> enumClass;`